# Hello! I'm recently trying to work with nativescript+angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

What's a good source for tutorials besides the "playground' and the book. I'm currently trying out the "playground" but I can see it better helping me after I get other details down.

Answer (score 1):

Start here: [Nativescript + Angular Tutorial](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/introduction)